# Problem with bash code

Tags: linux, bash

```
function dec_to_bin {   

if [ $# != 2 ]  
then
    return -1
else
    declare -a ARRAY[30]
    declare -i INDEX=0
    declare -i TEMP=$2
    declare -i TEMP2=0 

    while [ $TEMP -gt 0 ]
    do
        TEMP2="$TEMP%2"
        #printf "%d" "$TEMP2"
        ARRAY[$INDEX]=$TEMP2
        TEMP=$TEMP/2
        INDEX=$[ $INDEX + 1 ]  #note

    done

    for (( COUNT=INDEX; COUNT>-1; COUNT--)){

        printf "%d" "${ARRAY[$COUNT]}"  <<LINE 27
        #echo -n ${ARRAY[$COUNT]}       <<LINE 28
    }
fi
 }
```

why is this code giving this error

```
q5.sh: line 27: ARRAY[$COUNT]: unbound variable
```

same error comes with line 28 if uncommented

One more question, I am confused with the difference b/w '' and "" used in bash scripting any link to some nice article will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me except that you can't do `return -1`. The usual error value is `1`.

The error message is because you have `set -u` and you're starting your `for` loop at `INDEX` instead of `INDEX-1` (`${ARRAY[INDEX]}` will always be empty because of the way your `while` loop is written). Since you're using `%d` in your `printf` statement, empty variables will print as "0" (if `set -u` is not in effect).

Also, it's meaningless to declare an array with a size. Arrays in Bash are completely dynamic.

I would code the `for` loop with a test for `0` (because the `-1` looks confusing since it can't be the index of an numerically indexed array):

```
for (( COUNT=INDEX - 1; COUNT>=0; COUNT--))
```

This form is deprecated:

```
INDEX=$[ $INDEX + 1 ]
```

Use this instead:

```
INDEX=$(( $INDEX + 1 ))
```

or this:

```
((INDEX++))
```

I also recommend using lower case or mixed case variables as a habit to reduce the chance of variable name collision with shell variables.

You're not using `$1` for anything.